# Applications Permissions Manager for Kit Kat 4.4.2

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, permissions

Before KitKat 4.4.2 there were a variety of Applications Permissions Manager. They worked but with the release if KitKat 4.4.2 they no longer work. This was a non root application so it ran on non rooted phones.

The ability to disable permissions on Applications is very useful as some need way to many permissions. Unfortunately the Google has no filter on searching for applications based on what they access. So Application Permissions Manager was an excellent security tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The permissions manager feature of Android is not complete yet and strictly speaking it should not be accessible. In 4.4.2 Google have removed the method that apps such as [App Ops](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.findsdk.apppermission) and [App Ops 4.3 / 4.4 KitKat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.colortiger.appopsinstaller) used.

As far as I know there is currently no way to access this any more. You will have to wait for Google to finish implementing it and provide a built-in method to access, or wait for someone to find another way to access it.

Quote from Color Tiger the developer of one of the apps on [AndroidPolice](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/12/09/android-4-4-2-kot49h-is-already-rolling-out-to-nexus-devices-here-are-the-ota-zip-links-for-manual-updating/):

> Still not working, but here's a quick update:
>
> See [line 309](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/b568548747c9b137d7da05fcdbb84f157273b3db/src/com/android/settings/Settings.java) - those are
>   the allowed fragments that can be shown. AppOps was in that commit 3
>   days ago (line 329), but in the 4.2.2 build that's being sent out that
>   line is removed (we've decompiled the Settings.apk).
>
> We're looking
>   for a possible different entry point (another Activity to accept
>   commands to load the AppOpsSummary fragment), but it doesn't look
>   good.

**UPDATE:** Apparently Google uses App Ops as an internal testing and debugging tool – it was never designed to be seen by end users, which is why it wasn't given a spot in the system settings, or even the developer options. [Source](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/12/11/googler-app-ops-was-never-meant-for-end-users-used-for-internal-testing-and-debugging-only/)